# How do I attach a text to the vertices of a cube in three.js? Also, Can I add a Text at any point inside the Cube?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to create a cube using three.js for a project. I need to add text to vertices and at different points inside the cube. Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: I have created a cube and tried attaching image maps of texts to the vertices but it isn't fruitful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some basic code examples of using Sprite objects in Three.js, check out:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Sprites.html

And for an easy way to create images that contain text to use as your sprite textures, check out the sample code at:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Texture-From-Canvas.html

I think a combination of these two ideas will achieve what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have label-style texts, so that the text begins at a specific point, but is always oriented with the camera and easily readable no matter the camera position, you can use sprites. (example of canvas-created text label sprites: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFHSV.jpg - here they are rendered on a separate pass to that they are never obscured by the scene but you can do it on the same pass)

If that's what you are looking for, I'd suggest first checking the Sprites examples, and learn to attach some static image as a sprite to correct position in the scene. After you get that working, you modify the code so that you generate the text to an image canvas using standard Javascript Canvas functions, and using that image as the sprite.