# How do I add labels to structures in three.js onMouseClick?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

How can I add a label to a structure using three.js library onMouseClick?

Comment: How about https://www.google.fi/search?q=three.js+label http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=three.js+text http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=three.js+label http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447821/how-to-add-label-to-a-three-mesh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683727/three-js-text-next-to-line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038956/how-do-i-attach-a-text-to-the-vertices-of-a-cube-in-three-js-webgl-also-can-i  for starters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onmousedown event shoot a ray and detect the objects that are intersected. And then you can open a div. Please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683727/three-js-text-next-to-line) question I asked before.